# Python: Only exponentiate array if values is not equal to zero

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statsmodels

I have the below function in which I run several regressions. Some estimated coefficients are outputted as '0s' and naturally when they're exponentiated they turn into '1s'.

Ideally, I would have `sm.OLS()` output 'blanks' rather than 'zeros' in those cases where the estimated coefficient is zero. But I've tried and this doesn't seem possible.

So, alternatively, I would prefer to keep zeros rather than 1s. This would require not exponentiating the zeros in this line of the code: `exp_coefficients=np.exp(results.params)`

How could I do this?

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

df_index = []
coef_mtr = [] # start with an empty list
for x in df_main.project_x.unique():


df_holder=df_main[df_main.project_x == x]
    X = df_holder.drop(['unneeded1', 'unneeded2','unneeded3'], axis=1)
    X['constant']=1 
    Y = df_holder['sales']

    eq=sm.OLS(y, X)
    results=eq.fit()

    exp_coefficients=np.exp(results.params)
#   print(exp_coefficients)
    coef_mtr.append(exp_coefficients)
    df_index.append(x)

coef_mtr = np.array(coef_mtr)

# create a dataframe with this data
df_columns = [f'coef_{n}' for n in range(coef_mtr.shape[1])]
df_matrix=pd.DataFrame(data = coef_mtr, index = df_index, columns = df_columns)
```

Comment: Please can you fix the indentation and give the current output for a small df example (one that creates itself e.g. `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [...], ...})`) with the current and desired output?

Comment: `numpy.where(array != 0, f(array), 0)`

Comment: @PaulH, where do I introduce the 'np.exp' function in what you just proposed?

Comment: in that example, `f` is any function that returns an array that's the same length as the input

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest would probably be using the `where` *keyword* (not the function) as in

```
out = np.exp(in_,where=in_!=0)
```

This will skip al zero values. But because when I say skip I mean skip this will leave the corresponding values in out uninitialized. We therefore need to preset them to zero:

```
out = np.zeros_like(in_)
np.exp(in_,where=in_!=0,out=out)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate how this can be applied to my code? I can't seem to figure it out. I tried implementing it and get a `NameError: name 'in_' is not defined` error.

Comment: @StatsScared Well, `in_` corresponds to whatever your input is, glancing at your code `results.params` looks like a good candidate.